# QR Codes conversion

Tags: qr-code

I have a **text to QR code converter**. I want to use it to create QR codes like Website URL, YouTube Video, Google Maps Location, Telephone Number, Skype Call, SMS Message, Email Address, Email Message, Contact Details (VCARD), Event (VCALENDAR), Tlephone Number

Can you give me the codes to create it like I got to create Email-

```
MATMSG:
TO:xyz@abc.com;
SUB:I am sending this email using QR code;
BODY:I have stored all of your letters in QR codes.
[Add more here]
Thanks
[Your Name];;
```

You can check my [QR code generator](http://www.gauravtips.in/test/rech)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that only some QR code readers will recognize those different types and it's not universal for various phones/devices.  You are better off keeping it simple with text string/URL until all devices adhere to standard.  Android seems to support the most types and the reference implementation is their Barcode Scanner which is also open sourced on google code (zxing).

- http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

You can view their source for how they generate the different types... Then compare your output to theirs with this online generator:

- http://zxing.appspot.com/generator

Comment: Congrats! can you select my answer as accepted (green check)?  I still don't know how to do it myself, but trust it solved your issue.